# Getting "cursor "_django_curs_140244427998976_3" does not exist" error

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating modelforms. I have managed to pull the fields i want to use from my tables (using postgresql):

Table:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    Question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Response = models.TextField()
    Client = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Planit_location = models.ForeignKey(Planit_location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Response
```

Form:

```
class ResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = ('Response', 'Topic', 'Client')
        widgets = {
           'Response': Textarea(attrs={'rows':3, 'cols':200}),
        }
```

I want to now add in the Planit_locaiton field, but when i do i get the cursor error as stated in the title. Not sure why. Here is the Location table:

```
class Planit_location(models.Model):
    Planit_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Planit_location
```

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" name="uploadform" style="margin-left: 16px">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>Add Data</h4>
    <table>
            {{ qform.as_table }}
            {{ rform.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def adddata(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    username = request.user.username

if request.method == 'POST':
    qform = QuestionForm(request.POST)
    rform = ResponseForm(request.POST)
    if qform.is_valid() and rform.is_valid():
        qf = qform.save()
        rf = rform.save(commit=False)
        rf.Question = qf
        rf.save()
        return render(request, 'app/adddatatest.html', {
           "qform": QuestionForm(),
           "rform": ResponseForm(),
           "username": username,
        })
else:
    qform = QuestionForm()
    rform = ResponseForm()
return render(request, 'app/adddatatest.html', {
    "qform": QuestionForm(),
    "rform": ResponseForm(),
    "username": username,
})
```

EDIT

Traceback:

```
db_1             | 2018-09-21 15:35:12.284 UTC [58] ERROR:  relation "app_planit_location" does not exist at character 153
db_1             | 2018-09-21 15:35:12.284 UTC [58] STATEMENT:  DECLARE 
"_django_curs_140423080417024_3" NO SCROLL CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT "app_planit_location"."id", "app_planit_location"."Planit_location" FROM "app_planit_location"
db_1             | 2018-09-21 15:35:12.285 UTC [58] ERROR:  cursor "_django_curs_140423080417024_3" does not exist
db_1             | 2018-09-21 15:35:12.285 UTC [58] STATEMENT:  CLOSE "_django_curs_140423080417024_3"

Exception Type: OperationalError at /adddata/
Exception Value: cursor "_django_curs_140244427998976_3" does not exist
```

Comment: Please postv _at least_ the full traceback (and eventually read it, that's usually how one debugs an exception). Oh and fix your code snippet's indentation too.

Comment: Also - totally unrelated - after a successful post, you always want to redirect the user (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Oh and yes: the variable `username` is only defined if the user is authenticated, but unconditionally used. This will raise a NameError if you execute this view as an anonymous user.

Comment: i think i may have found the issue. In my postgresql the increment id for location is this "integer Auto Increment [nextval('"app_pPlanit_location_id_seq"')] ". The extra p might be messing it up